# Solving inequality. Did I do it right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Solve the following inequality: $$5(y-2)-3(y+4)\ge2y-20$$

I made calclations and I found:

$$
0\ge2
$$

What does it mean? Are my calculations right?

Here's how I did it:

$$
5(y-2)-3(y+4)\ge2y-20\\
5y-10-3y-12\ge2y-20\\
2y-22\ge2y-20\\
2y\ge2y+2\\
2y-2y\ge2\\
0\ge2
$$

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: It's right. The last inequality tells you there is no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. The last result tells you that there are no solutions for $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to satisfy the inequality $\displaystyle 5(y-2)-3(y+4)\geqslant2y-20$.